# Unable to display validation Messages -Angular 6

Tags: validation, angular6

I am working on Angular 6 reactive forms.Facing problem with validation.Details are as follows.
1)I am only able to display username is required message.Where as others are displayed with a blank alert box.Please check the images below.
I am not able to understand where the problem lies.

Also I am unable to add the type script code for the component.Posting it in images

HTML Code

```html
<div class="signUpForm">
  <p class="formHeader">Enter Your Details</p>
  <form class="container" [formGroup]="signUpForm">
    <input type="text" name="userName" formControlName="userName" placeholder="UserName" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="5" required>
    <div *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['userName'].invalid && (signUpForm.controls['userName'].dirty || signUpForm.controls['userName'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
      <span *ngIf="userName.errors.minLength=">length must be greater than 3 </span>
      <div *ngIf="userName.errors.required">
        <p>UserName is required</p>
      </div>
      <p *ngIf="userName.errors.maxLength">UserName length must be less than 5 </p>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <div *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['password'].invalid && (signUpForm.controls['password'].dirty || signUpForm.controls['password'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
      <div *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['password'].errors.required">
        password is required.
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="confirmPassword" formControlName="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
    <div *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['confirmPassword'].invalid && (signUpForm.controls['confirmPassword'].dirty || signUpForm.controls['confirmPassword'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
      <div *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['confirmPassword'].errors.required">
        password is required.
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Problem lies here]

[image: Required validation messages are working]

[image: code[![][3]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaB8B.png)
[TS code][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cohkr.png)

[image: code 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error properties are *maxlength* and *minlength* and not *minLength*, *maxLength*. Html code look something like below.

```
<div *ngIf="signUpForm.controls.userName.errors?.maxlength">length must be less than 6 character!</div>
```

Please Read more: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

I have done a small working code snippet also. Please go through it and understand more.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ybal5b

Comment: thank you for the answer.i figured it out but not remembering how.Accepting the answer since i've done similar changes